# Docker with .net 6 + multiple projects = long time restore

Tags: c#, .net, docker, dockerfile, .net-6.0

I have .NET 6 project with a structure like this:

```
root:
DockerFile
.dockerignore
Project.sln
-src
--Project1
---*.csproj
--Project2
---*.csproj
--Project3
---*.csproj
--Project4 //library
--Project3 //library
```

I have a DockerFile like this:

```
#Build Stage
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-focal AS build
WORKDIR /source
COPY . .  
RUN dotnet restore "./src/pp.WebApi/pp.WebApi.csproj" --disable-parallel
RUN dotnet publish "./src/pp.WebApi/pp.WebApi.csproj" --runtime win-x64  -c release -o --no-restore /app

#Serve Stage
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-focal
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app ./

EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "pp.WebApi.dll"]
```

This is what my `.dockerignore` looks like:

```
**/.dockerignore
**/.env
**/.git
**/.gitignore
**/.vs
**/.vscode
**/*.*proj.user
**/azds.yaml
**/charts
**/bin
**/obj
**/Dockerfile
**/Dockerfile.develop
**/docker-compose.yml
**/docker-compose.*.yml
**/*.dbmdl
**/*.jfm
**/secrets.dev.yaml
**/values.dev.yaml
**/.toolstarget

### Csharp ###
## Ignore Visual Studio temporary files, build results, and
## files generated by popular Visual Studio add-ons.

# User-specific files
*.suo
*.user
*.userosscache
*.sln.docstates

# User-specific files (MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio)
*.userprefs

# Build results
[Dd]ebug/
[Dd]ebugPublic/
[Rr]elease/
[Rr]eleases/
x64/
x86/
bld/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/
[Ll]og/
```

My problem is that when I try to build:

```
docker build --rm -t rr:latest . --memory="16g" --no-cache
```

`Dotnet restore` command takes a long time (about 40 minutes). And also I have communicates about failed to download of packages.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-restore

> In most cases, you don't need to explicitly use the dotnet restore command, since if a NuGet restore is necessary, the following commands run it implicitly:

```
dotnet new
dotnet build
dotnet build-server
dotnet run
dotnet test
dotnet publish
dotnet pack
```

So you don't need to call explicitly RUN dotnet restore.

There is cache and maybe you need a NugeGet private repository to proxy-cache public dependencies.

Comment: Ok but if I remove line with `dotnet restore` i must also remove `--no-restore` parameter from `dotnet publish`, yes? In this situation `publish` will triger restore and it also takes 30minutes.

Comment: Yes for sure. But idealy you project must be release and build before create docker image. But if build your project take 30min because it's a big project you have to optimize that.